# Setup jenkins job on opwenshift without creating repo on openshift

Tags: jenkins, openshift

I have to do same as following.
1. Just create one gear for jenkins.
2. Create job in jenkins to fetch from github / bitbucket. 
3. Build

https://openshift.redhat.com/community/forums/openshift/jenkins-stuff

Issue is I am getting "Host key verification failed" as when git checks out ssh keys are not added.

So, I did search and followed steps mentioned in 
https://openshift.redhat.com/community/forums/openshift/jenkins-stuff

1. Go to $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR
2. Create wrapper.sh  with

   ID_RSA="$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/.ssh/jenkins_id_rsa"
   ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i $ID_RSA $1 $2
3. export GIT_SSH env variable in .bash_profile

   export GIT_SSH=/var/lib/openshift//app-root/data/wrapper.sh

Now, in jenkins still I am getting same error.

Comment: Have you solved this? I have the same [issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33403221/how-to-configure-jenkins-for-clone-bitbucket-repo-and-deploy-in-openshift) and I think that the jenkins slave that runs the build can't see neither the GIT_SSH variable or the wrapper file.

Answer (score 0):

Is your wrapper.sh executable? Mark it executable with `chmod +x wrapper.sh`.

Answer (score 0):

no number.

/var/lib/openshift/<**number**>/app-root/data

```
export GIT_SSH=$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/wrapper.sh
```

or

```
>rhc env-set -a jenkins GIT_SSH=$OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/wrapper.sh
```